# docker-compose up vs docker-compose up service1 service2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

I have the following docker-compose file below. If I run `docker-compose up` everything functions properly. If I do however `docker-compose up minio1 minio2 minio3 minio4` the volumes are not created, and I do not see the following logs. It does not create the volumes I am assuming. I have many other services in the real docker-compose.yml file, I don't want to run `docker-compose up` and start every service all the time. How do I only start those 4 services AND create volumes/networks?

**This does not appear with docker-compose up minio1 minio2 ...**

```
Creating volume "robot_models1" with default driver
Creating volume "robot_models2" with default driver  
Creating volume "robot_models3" with default driver  
Creating volume "robot_models4" with default driver
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  minio1:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2018-07-10T01-42-11Z
    volumes:
      - models1:/export
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: access123123
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: secret123123
    command: server http://minio1/export http://minio2/export http://minio3/export http://minio4/export

  minio2:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2018-07-10T01-42-11Z
    volumes:
      - models2:/export
    ports:
      - "9002:9000"
    depends_on:
      - minio1
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: access123123
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: secret123123
    command: server http://minio1/export http://minio2/export http://minio3/export http://minio4/export

  minio3:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2018-07-10T01-42-11Z
    volumes:
      - models3:/export
    ports:
      - "9003:9000"
    depends_on:
      - minio2
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: access123123
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: secret123123
    command: server http://minio1/export http://minio2/export http://minio3/export http://minio4/export

  minio4:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2018-07-10T01-42-11Z
    volumes:
      - models4:/export
    ports:
      - "9004:9000"
    depends_on:
      - minio3
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: access123123
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: secret123123
    command: server http://minio1/export http://minio2/export http://minio3/export http://minio4/export

  ## By default this config uses default local driver,
  ## For custom volumes replace with volume driver configuration.
volumes:
  models1:
  models2:
  models3:
  models4:
```

**docker-compose version:**

```
docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471
docker-py version: 3.4.1
CPython version: 3.6.5
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

> docker-compose up -d minio1 minio2 minio3 minio4

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You have to execute these 4 commands:

```
docker-compose up minio1 
docker-compose up minio2 
docker-compose up minio3 
docker-compose up minio4
```

**Explanation**

Reason why you cannot do `docker-compose up minio1 minio2 minio3 minio4` is because you're executing: `docker-compose up [serviceName] [entrypoint] [parameter1] [parameter2]...`
I.e, docker-compose lets you execute only a service among defined in compose file, specifying a new entrypoint with its parameters if you want, but not several services in only one command.

Comment: This is not correct, `docker-compose up minio1 minio2 minio3 minio4` **does** start those 4 services! See the [`docker-compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar challenge on my current project. That broght me to the idea of writing a small script which I called `docker-compose-profile` (or short: `dcp`). I published this yesterday on GitLab as [docker-compose-profile](https://gitlab.com/michapoe/docker-compose-profile). So in short: I now can start several predefined docker-compose profiles using a command like `dcp -p all-minio "up -d"`. A profile may contain a subset of all defined services in your `docker.compose.yml`. With this mechanism it would be easy to start up several sets of services defined seperately in a `dcp.yml`. Defining some steps for startup it would also be possible to first start all minio services and a next step would ramp up other services.
Feel free to try it out and give some feedback or suggestions for further improvements.

So two scenarious couold be covered: a) only startup your minio stuff b) first start minio services and continue with other services.

Comment: You might wanna take a look into https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/ ;)

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But my approach is way more than docker-compose profiles. Have You read my readme?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually check whether the volumes are created? Running `docker-compose up minio1 minio2 minio3 minio4` will up those containers and all their dependencies such as `depends_on` containers and volumes but will output only the logs of the containers explicitly listed in the command.

I.e. the volumes are actually created but this is just not logged to you since you only attached to the logs of the containers! (and volumes are created by `docker-compose` and not by the containers themselves).

> I have many other services in the real docker-compose.yml file, I don't want to run docker-compose up and start every service all the time.

Starting with [`docker-compose` 1.28.0](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.28.0) the new [service profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) are just made for that! With `profiles` you can mark services to be only started in specific profiles:

```yaml
services:
  minio1:
    profiles: ["minio"]
    #...

  minio2:
    profiles: ["minio"]
    #...

  minio3:
    profiles: ["minio"]
    #...

  minio4:
    profiles: ["minio"]
    #...

  service1:
    profiles: ["other"]
    #...

  service2:
    profiles: ["other"]
    #...

  service3:
    profiles: ["other"]
    #...

  service4:
    profiles: ["other"]
    #...
```

```sh
docker-compose up # start only your default services (without `profiles`)
docker-compose --profile minio up # start default and minio services
docker-compose --profile other up # start default and "other" services
```

You may also consider splitting your services into [multiple `docker-compose.yml` files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files):

```sh
# only start services in docker-compose.minio.yml
docker-compose -f docker-compose.minio.yml up

# merge docker-compose.minio.yml with docker-compose.yml
# and start all contained services
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.minio.yml up
```